# flexigrid refresh using javascript

Tags: flexigrid

Refresh the flexigrid data on dropdown (select) index changed or rebind the flexigrid on index change in javascript or clear the flexigrid data on select change

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking to bind the grid's refresh with another element, you can use

```
$('#flex1').flexReload()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following. On selection change of the Severity, the flexigrid reloads with the data for the selected severity

```
<select id='ddlSeverity' onchange="setSeverity($('#ddlSeverity option:selected').attr('value'));">
                            <option value="1">Severity 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Severity 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Severity 3</option>
                            <option value="4">Severity 4</option>
</select>



$(document).ready(function () {

 function setSeverity(severity) {
//Construct the URL to be called. 
        var urlAction = '@Url.Action("RequestQueueBySeverity", "Home", new { severity = "__BOGUS__" })';
//Replace the bogus parameter with the parameter to be passed
        urlAction = urlAction.replace("__BOGUS__", severity);

        $('#flex1')
        .flexOptions({
            url: urlAction,
            newp: 1
        }).flexReload();
    }

}
```

Please mark as answer if it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

For efficient reloading, you can try this:

```
$("#flexigrid")[0].grid.populate()
```